# extract elements from list of lists with variable number of elements and NAs R

Tags: r, list, sublist

I've got a list containing groups of two sublist. The problem is that some of the sublist are NAs and that those that are not contain a variable number of elements. How can I extract the elements from the second sublist (the one with a variable number of elements)?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
x <- c('a','b','c')
mytestlist <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {mytestlist[[i]] <- list(cat=sample(x,1),nums=rnorm(sample(c(1,2,3),1)))}
ind <- sample(1:10,3)
for (i in ind) {mytestlist[[i]] <- NA}
z <- lapply(mytestlist,function(x) {if (is.na(mytestlist[[x]])) c(a=0,b=1,c=0) else mytestlist[[x]]$nums})
```

Comment: There's a few problems here but `lapply(mytestlist,function(x) { if( all(is.na(x)) ){ c(a=0,b=1,c=0)}else{ x$nums } } )
` should work.

Comment: You could also test for the list names:  `lapply(mytestlist, function(x) if('nums' %in% names(x)) x$nums)`

Comment: @Justin thanks your solution is very elegant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this can be marked as answered:

SimonO101's solution (checking for `NA` values):

```
lapply(mytestlist, 
       function(x) { 
          if( all(is.na(x)) ){ 
               c(a=0,b=1,c=0) 
          } else { 
               x$nums 
          } 
       })
```

My solution (checking for named list elements):

```
lapply(mytestlist, 
       function(x) {
          if('nums' %in% names(x)) {
             x$nums
          } else {
             c(a=0, b=1, c=0)
          }
       })
```